# How to join two tables with one similar column into one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, A and B and C.

### sample data for Table A

```
nid   tid
101    3
101    4
101    7
103    3
103    5
104    2
104    4
104    7
```

### sample data for Table B

```
tid   name
2     ram
3     shyam
4     krishna
5     shiv
7     narad
```

## What I want is, in a Third Table C

```
id   nid   labels
1    101   shyam, krishna, narad
2    103   shyam, shiv
3    104   ram, krishna, narad
```

I know how to do this with PHP, but is there any way to do this mysql alone?

Both tables (A and B) have thousands of records and don't have any unique column at the moment.

I tried GROUP_CONCAT but I could not construct desired output.

**Edit 1 - I forgot to mention that Table C already has id and nid column inserted, while labels column is empty. So I need help in constructing some query which can update all records of Table C with labels mentioned as above.**

Thanks. Regards,

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` is the solution. Show us what have you tried with it and tell us what's wrong with the results.

Comment: where is the `ID` form tableC coming from? is it autogenerated sequence based on the results of joining A and B?

Comment: @JohnWoo `id` of table C is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and No it's not based on joining

Comment: `SELECT nid, labels` FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON table1.tid=table2.tid`
then use a cursor and add this result in the third table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will insert the records on `TableC`. Since `ID` is an autogenerated column, you can omit this in the `INSERT` clause.

```
INSERT INTO TableC(Nid, Labels)
SELECT  a.nid, GROUP_CONCAT(b.Name) Labels
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON a.tid = b.tid
GROUP   BY a.nid
```

Comment: your query works if I insert both `nid` and `labels`. but as i mentioned in Edit-1, of my question, `Table C` already has `nid` (which was actually inserted from some other source, so I dont want to truncate and use insert). I want to **Update** `Table C` with `labels` inserted as demonstrated in your query.

Comment: i found a way, although it increased one step and one query, i used this query to merge the data from above query into new table, having nid already inserted.
`UPDATE TableD AS t1 JOIN( SELECT id, nid, labels from TableC ) AS t2 ON t2.nid = t1.nid 
set t1.Labels = t2.labels`